# How do I unzip a .zip file on a Chromebook

Tags: zip, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I downloaded a zip file on my Chromebook. I see the file when I got to "chrome://files".

How do I unzip it? Clicking on it merely lets me view its contents.

Answer (score 3):

Create a destination folder.  Open the archive in Chrome OS Files.  Select and copy what you want, and paste it to the destination folder.  You may be able to drag and drop as well.

Answer (score 0):

ChromeOS is coming with an unzip util that should work for you with clicking on zip files. You don't need to open the terminal for that.
If for some reason you don't have it 'by default' try:

- Go to *about:flags*
- Enable Open archive.
- Restart the Chromebook.

Comment: I do not have this flag? What is  the exact `chrome://flags/#fragmentidentifier`

Answer (score -3):

Ummm, NO, clicking on the zip folder to view it's contents does NOT unzip the file.  Just like on a PC, clicking on a zip file to open it and view its contents does not unzip it.  To unzip the folder, you right click on it and then select unzip.  But there's no such option on Chrome...

Comment: The reason for the down votes is because ChromeOS uses some sophistication and actually mounts the ZIP files. In essence ChromeOS never actually unzips in terms of the typical sense, the files are accessed by tunneling into the mounted directory, but fully accessible.