# Location of mounted Zip File on Chromebook via Crosh

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

See this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/624919/492155) for context.

I believe these steps could easily be recreated via `crosh` (Chrome Shell) given the location of the mounted media. Anyone know this path?

Any references to Chrome specific folder hierarchies and their typical contents would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have developer mode enabled you could install  homebrew [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation) and then install p7zip . The zip extractor does not mount the zip archive. Just makes the files viewable. I zipped an html file to open the zip and to see what the path is by opening the html file in the zip and the path I got was `externalfile:dmboannefpncccogfdikhmhpmdnddgoe%3A~%252FMyFiles%252FDownloads%252Findex%252Ezip%3A6091f428a231dff3a64a2706582439c9ddf933a7/index.html`
You can see that this uses the path but that all the data runs through the zip extractor extension. I mean I know that all file systems are mounted under `/media` (Which is accessible without chrome os developer mode) But opened zip files do not appear here. The files probably appear in the extensions temp folder just like it would do on windows. Short answer: No, it is not possible unless you have developer mode enabled (Seems a little excessive to enable it just for zip files)

Short answer: This is not possible with the context you have given.